# How to know if the page was loaded from a popup window

Tags: php, popupwindow

How Can i know using PHP, Whether the current request is from a popup window or from a normal browser window ?

--
Thank you

Comment: a popup window **IS** a normal browser window.

Comment: Your client-side code would have to tell your server-side code that this is happening.  When opening the "popup" window you could include a query string value indicating to the server-side code that it's a "popup" window.  Other than explicitly telling the server-side code, however, there's no other way.  It's not really the server-side code's concern in which window the client is displaying the content.

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: If you control the content in the pop-up window, why not just include a flag with the request (you don't mention what type) that it is from the pop-up?

Comment: @Marc B it would be interesting to see how many of your initial answers are condescending and provide no real answer... many of them are wonderful and very well thought out. Many, like the one above though don't seem to help. You don't seem to be a fan of inference.

Comment: @mjayt: which is why that was a comment, to signify that it's NOT an answer. I'm also not a big fan of unecessarily terse questions, with no context to figure out exactly what the end result should be. Terse question, terse comment/answer.

Comment: Fair enough... I bet you're a delight to hang out with. Seems you could just ignore the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it with PHP.

You may want to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to determine how the user reached the page to determine if it's a popup window.

If you have the option of using JQuery then you can use `$(window).height();` to determine the size of the window.

With raw JS things get a little more complicated: http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewport-size-width-and-height-javascript

Answer (score 1):

if you open popup yourself you can open window with query string like this:

```
window.open("page.php?popup=1");
```

then you can check this query string in php like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['popup'])){
    echo 'popup window';
}else{
    echo 'normal window';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side, browser window are client side. there is no way to know this using only PHP... you need a client side language that can tell the difference, and pass it through to your PHP script.

But as was already said in the comments, there is no inherent difference between a popup and a 'normal' browser window... just as there is no difference between 2 instances of a browser and 2 tabs in the same browser window...